# Implementing menu with submenu

Tags: html, css

i want to create a menu that looks like that in the picture i created.

[image]

I'm having some problems with the CSS part.

```
         <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Header</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <img src="">
                        <a href="#">test</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Header 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS-Part

```
.plane ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 20px;
}

.plane ul li {
}

.plane ul li a {
color: #7d7d7d;
text-decoration: none;
}

.plane ul li a:hover {
color: #3a3a3a;
cursor: pointer;
}

.plane ul li a.current {
color: black;
}

.plane ul li ul li {
float: left;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
margin: 5px;
width: 125px;
height: 60px;
border-radius: 2px;
}

.plane ul li ul li img {
width: 120px;
height: 40px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.plane ul li ul li:hover {
background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Hope you can help me with this problem. It looks easy but i cant figure out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: can you put it in a fiddle?

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/jn5cL0nq/

Comment: Probably not what you want, but giving the .plane.ul a fixed height (i used 100px to test) does provide the structure you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

```
.plane ul  li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jn5cL0nq/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing list item type from list item to block.

ex

```
.plane ul  li {
    clear:both;
    display:block;
}
```

and then

```
.plane ul  li ul li{
     float left;
     clear:none;
 }
```

Tested and works :D

Comment: thanks but its not what it shuld look like. with your solution the list-items are among each other and not side by side

Comment: Ok. Check it now. i've added one more line :P
dont miss to mark as answer if this is ok :D :D